# Animation subclass

Tags: python, kivy

in Animation class, how to set d = 0.4,  t = 'in_out_quad'  by default? Can I use subclass for that?

```py
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.animation import Animation

KV = """
Label
    text: '123'
    on_touch_down: app.test()
"""
class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        self.root = Builder.load_string(KV)

    def test(self):
        a = Animation(x = 500, d = .2, t = 'in_out_quad')
        a.start(self.root)

MyApp().run()
```

Tried something like this (with no success):

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.animation import Animation

KV = """

Label
    text: '123'
    on_touch_down: app.test()

<MyAnim>:
    d: .2
    t: 'in_out_quad'
"""

class MyAnim(Animation):
    pass

class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        self.root = Builder.load_string(KV)

    def test(self):
        a = MyAnim(x = 500)
        a.start(self.root)

MyApp().run()
```

I just want not to write the values of the arguments d and t many times if they are the same in my project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tested this, but I think you could just put those defaults in your class definition:

```
class MyAnim(Animation):
    def __init__(self, **kw):
        super(MyAnim, self).__init__(d = .2, t = 'in_out_quad', **kw)
```

Of course, if you use `MyAnim` and specify another `t=` or `d=`, you will get an error.

That error can be avoided by only adding the default values if they are not already specified:

```
class MyAnim(Animation):
    def __init__(self, **kw):
        if 'd' not in kw:
            kw['d'] = 0.2
        if 't' not in kw:
            kw['t'] = 'in_out_quad'
        super(MyAnim, self).__init__(**kw)
```

Comment: Yes, if I pass another d (d = 1 for example) as an argument, I get an error. Could you clarify why this happens?

Comment: The error happens because the super class (`Animation`) gets two setting for the same parameter. I have added another version of the code to avoid that.